# vbscript adds Option to drop box and knocks out javascript function updatelist HTA File

Tags: javascript, vbscript, hta

Hey guys have here an HTA File. There is a vbscript which reads a file and add based on this a option to a drop box. Later in this HTA file there is javascript which use update list and other functions to update a second dropbox based on selection in the first dropbox. The vbscript only edit the first dropbox. I get no error but my Javascript makes no selection any more it just uses all the time the same selection. How to fix? Here some bit of code.

Edit: First i have to say thanks so much for your work Teemu. You spend so much time on my question. Respect. But yes really but. The script is the best, i have set uped everything like you said. So there is a little error in Line 27: `customers[cust].createReleaseOptions(cust);` I have made a picture of the error and of my setup:
[For image klick  here!](http://img406.imageshack.us/img406/5483/errorhj.png)

Hope you can help me one more time :)

Comment: Hard to say with this information. Can you post `Option` declaration too?

Comment: Ehh, this was not exactly what I was meaning, but rather the constructor function of `Option`. I'm not sure what `optionName` contains, but seems like your'e definiting `object.select2.options[x] twice. First in `Option`-object and then again two lines later in your original code.

Comment: Please dont't send the whole code, only the `Option` function.

Comment: i wrote the whole code because dont know whats the Option function. Sorry i  can only program a little bit c#

Comment: There seems not to be `Option`-function at all, only empty declaration in VBScript can be found. Hence the `optionName` is `undefined`. Strange that you haven't got any error message.

Comment: so means this you cant help me or is this what causes my problem? Bevore i added the part which reads out the value of the text file and add the value to the dropdownbox select1 everything worked.

Comment: This is causing your problem. There should be a JavaScript-function named `Option`, which would handle arguments in `optionName=new Option(...)`

Comment: Than i should use JavaScript instead of VBScript to add the new option?

Comment: I have seen in your profile you know javascript can you help me to add this to my code. I dont want a copy and paste solution beacause i want to learn. Poste it as answer so i can give you a reputation.

Comment: @Teemu can you please have a look on my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>CATIA Starttool</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION 
     ID="myCATIA" 
     APPLICATIONNAME="myCatia"
     SCROLL="no"
>

//****** Open last used environment and set it as default selection
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- THESE 5 FUNCTIONS REPLACE ALL MISSING CODE

// Reads textfile, file is created automatically, if not exist
function readCustomers(){
var fso,iStream,cust,n,tarr;
customers={};
fso=new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
iStream=fso.OpenTextFile('C:/Temp/CAD_Kunde.txt',1,true);
cust=iStream.ReadLine();
for(n=0;!iStream.AtEndOfStream;n++){
    tarr=iStream.ReadLine().split(';');
    customers[n]=new Customer(tarr);        
}
iStream.Close();
customers[0].selectionElement.selectedIndex=cust;
    customers[cust].createReleaseOptions(cust);
window.activeCustomer=cust;
return;
}

// Customer (environment) constructor function
function Customer(txt){
    var n,x=0;
    this.selectionElement=document.getElementById('select1');
    this.customerName=txt[0];
    this.catiaRelease=[];
    for(n=1;n<txt.length-1;n++){
        this.catiaRelease[n-1]=txt[n];
        x++;
    }
    this.len=x;
    this.defaultOption=parseInt(txt[txt.length-1]);
    this.selected=false;
    this.createCustomerOption();
}

// Creates customer (environment) options
Customer.prototype.createCustomerOption=function(){
    var opt;
    opt=document.createElement('OPTION');
    opt.text=this.customerName;
    opt.value=this.customerName;
    this.selectionElement.add(opt);
    return;
}

// Creates release options
Customer.prototype.createReleaseOptions=function(idx){
    var target,n,opt;
    target=document.getElementById('select2');
    target.length=0;
    for(n=0;n<this.len;n++){
        opt=document.createElement('OPTION');
        opt.text=this.catiaRelease[n];
        opt.value=this.catiaRelease[n];
        target.add(opt);    
    }
    target[this.defaultOption].selected=true;
    //target[0].selected=true; // Move comment line above, if this option is used
    window.activeCustomer=idx;
    return;
}

// Saves textfile
function saveCustomers(){
var fso,oStream,n,m,str='',cust=document.getElementById('select1');eos=cust.length;
fso=new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
oStream=fso.OpenTextFile('C:/Temp/CAD_Kunde.txt',2,true);
oStream.WriteLine(cust.selectedIndex);
for(n=0;n<eos;n++){
    str='';
    str+=customers[n].customerName+';';
    for(m=0;m<customers[n].len;m++){
        str+=customers[n].catiaRelease[m]+';';
    }
    str+=customers[n].defaultOption;
    oStream.WriteLine(str);
}
oStream.Close();
}


//***********

function OpenAction(object) {
   self.resizeTo(299,299);
   OpenActionVB();
   readCustomers();

}
//********

function RunScript(object) {
   saveCustomers();
   BetriebssystemKommando(object.select1.options[object.select1.selectedIndex].value,
                          object.select2.options[object.select2.selectedIndex].value,
                          select3=document.getElementById('OSName'),
                          object.select4.options[object.select4.selectedIndex].value,
                          object.select5.options[object.select5.selectedIndex].value,
                          object.select6.options[object.select6.selectedIndex].value);
}
//******** checking 64-Bit or 32-Bit

OS = navigator.userAgent;
if (OS.indexOf("Win")!=-1) { 
if ((OS.indexOf("Windows NT 5.1")!=-1) || (OS.indexOf("Windows XP")!=-1)) 
OSName="Win XP"; 
else if ((OS.indexOf("Windows NT 7.0")!=-1) || (OS.indexOf("Windows NT 6.1")!=-1)) 
OSName="Win 7"; 
else
OSName="Win Ver. Unknown"; 
// selection based on 64-Bit or 32-Bit
if ((OS.indexOf("WOW64")!=-1) || (OS.indexOf("x64")!=-1) || (OS.indexOf("Win64")!=-1) || (OS.indexOf("IA64")!=-1)) OSName= "DEFAULT_64"
else OSName="DEFAULT"
}
//********
//--></script>

<script language="vbscript">

Sub OpenActionVB( )

  cdiWorkDirRoot="C:\CDI"
  cdiBinaryRoot="i:\cad\catiav5\CDI"


  '*** CDI Software im Zugriff ?

  set objFSO = createObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  If objFSO.FolderExists(cdiBinaryRoot) then


    '*** CDIWORK Rootverzeichnis anlegen

    If not objFSO.FolderExists(cdiWorkDirRoot) then
      objFSO.CreateFolder( cdiWorkDirRoot )
    End if

    '*** CDIWORK Rootverzeichnis Vollzugriff für alle aus der Gruppe BGST-GL-PDMUSR

    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    If objFSO.FolderExists(cdiWorkDirRoot) Then
      intRunError = objShell.Run("%COMSPEC% /c Echo J| cacls " & cdiWorkDirRoot & " /e /c /g BAT\BGST-GL-PDMUSR:F ", 2, True)
      intRunError = objShell.Run("%COMSPEC% /c Echo Y| cacls " & cdiWorkDirRoot & " /e /c /g BAT\BGST-GL-PDMUSR:F ", 2, True)
    End If

    '*** CDIWORK Benutzerverzeichnis anlegen

    Set objWSHNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    userName=objWSHNetwork.UserName

    If not objFSO.FolderExists(cdiWorkDirRoot&"\"&userName) then
      objFSO.CreateFolder( cdiWorkDirRoot&"\"&userName )
    End if

    '*** CDIWORK Verzeichnisstruktur im Benutzerverzeichnis anlegen


    If not objFSO.FolderExists(cdiWorkDirRoot&"\"&userName&"\"&"WORK") then
      objFSO.CreateFolder( cdiWorkDirRoot&"\"&userName&"\"&"WORK")
    End if

    If not objFSO.FolderExists(cdiWorkDirRoot&"\"&userName&"\"&"INDEX") then
      objFSO.CreateFolder( cdiWorkDirRoot&"\"&userName&"\"&"INDEX")
    End if

    If not objFSO.FolderExists(cdiWorkDirRoot&"\"&userName&"\"&"LOG") then
      objFSO.CreateFolder( cdiWorkDirRoot&"\"&userName&"\"&"LOG")
    End if

    If not objFSO.FolderExists(cdiWorkDirRoot&"\"&userName&"\"&"RFCTRACEDIR") then
      objFSO.CreateFolder( cdiWorkDirRoot&"\"&userName&"\"&"RFCTRACEDIR")
    End if
  End if
End Sub
//*****************
Sub BetriebssystemKommando(Kunde,Version,Typ,Task,LocalSettings,LocalCache )

    Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strTmpName = "C:\Temp\CAD_Kunde.txt"
    Set objScript = objFS.CreateTextFile(strTmpName)

    objScript.Write Kunde
    objScript.Write select1


strCmdLine = "i:\metaph\pdmsetup & muxstart & dspstart -d & i:\catiav5\start\V5start.bat " & Kunde & " " & Kunde & "_" & OSName & " " &  Version & " " & Task & " " & " I:\catiav5\start " & LocalSettings & " " & LocalCache

   objScript.Close


   Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

   objShell.Run(strCmdLine)


End Sub

</script>

</head>

<body onload="OpenAction()" >

<style>
BODY
{
   background-color:buttonface;
   font-family: Helvetica;
   font-size: 10pt;
   margin-top: 10px;
   margin-left: 10px;
   margin-right: 10px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
}
</style>
<form name="formname">  
<table style="width: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="2"
 cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>         
      Environment <br>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="select1" id="select1" size="1" onchange="customers[this.selectedIndex].createReleaseOptions(this.selectedIndex);">
      </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
      Release
      </td>     
      <td>
            <select name="select2" size="1" onchange="customers[activeCustomer].defaultOption=this.selectedIndex;">
      </select>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
      Task
      </td>     
      <td>
      <select name="select4" size="1">
      <option value="DEFAULT">DEFAULT</option>
      <option value="AL2">AL2</option>
      <option value="DMU">DMU</option>
      <option value="EHD">EHD</option>
      <option value="FEM">FEM</option>
      <option value="IPPRO">IPPRO</option>
      <option value="EHD">EHD</option>
      <option value="KIN">KIN</option>
      <option value="NC">NC</option>
      <option value="ZADMIN">ZADMIN</option>
      </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
      <td>
      Delete user settings
      </td>     
      <td>
      <select name="select5" size="1">
      <option value="1">YES</option>
      <option value="0">NO</option>
      </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
      Delete local cache
      </td>     
      <td>
      <select name="select6" size="1">
      <option value="1">YES</option>
      <option value="0">NO</option>
      </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>        
      </td>     
      <td>
      <input id=runbutton  class="button" type="button" value="Run"  name="run_button"  onClick="RunScript(document.formname)">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

This should be working. Format your CAD_Kunde.txt as below:

```
1
BEHR;B18 SP4;B18 SP7;0
AUDI;B19 SP3;0
BMW;B19 SP3;0
BIT;B18 SP4;B19 SP3;B16 SP9;0
```

1st line = zero-based index pointing last used environment.

Other lines:
First in line there is your environment name, then all releases, and a number at end is a zero-based index, which release is active. All values separated by semicolon, no spaces or other non-printing characters allowed (except ENTER) at the end of the line. Last line in the file should be emptyline, and *only one* of those.

Code is not protected against errors in the textfile. Semicolon is not allowed to use as data.

Environments and releases are also easy to maintain, just update them into the textfile.

Program remembers all clicks on selectboxes, and saves the file every time `Run` is clicked. If needed, extra save-button is easy to add. If clicked release is not wanted to be saved, switch comment in `createReleases`-function with line above.

Comment: ok i followed the link and found a code. I just added my path to the text file. Where do i have to add the code and how do i ad the returning value to the dropdownbox select1 and select it as default?`<script language="JavaScript">
function ReadFiles()
{
   var fso, ts, s;
   var ForReading = 1;
   // Read the contents of the file.
   ts = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\\Temp\CAD_Kunde.txt", ForReading);
   s = ts.ReadLine();
   ts.Close();
}
</SCRIPT>`

Comment: Please make addings to your original question. I've already asked by SO, to move this conversation to chat because of too many comments.

Comment: problem is cant use chat because i havent enough reputations

Comment: @user1225282 I've found some issues from your code. In edited answer there are some proposes to fix problems. Hope you can understand my poor english.

Comment: i have problems to fix your second point. I know i have to remove `objOption.selected="selected"` but what i have to add instead.

Comment: @user1225282 Ähh, I'm not sure of this anymore. Is it OK, that I'll write read and write functions for Kunde.txt in JavaScript, and reform the `UploadList()`? Done by tomorrow?

Comment: oh yeah its ok. You are helping me so much.

Comment: Are you sure that you have that one single emptyline at the end of the textfile?. Make also sure, that you save the file in ANSI -format. The code worked in my tests exactly how it should be, no errors occured. Add `alert(cust);` before that error line, and send it to the same address, as earlier, I'll check it in a moment.

Comment: Yes im sure i have the empty line pressed once enter after the latest text line. Its saved in ANSI-format and it alerts `1`

Comment: Propably you have an extra space(s) at the beginning or at end of the Audi-line. Check the instructions in my answer. That emptyline at the end of the file means, that cursor should be alone on the line below the last dataline. Write lines your self, don't copypaste.

Comment: Haha you were right it wasnt coorect because it was copy&paste. Now i just have to write with VBScript a part wich check if the .txt exists and when not that it create the config file. You are a scripting god for me. I accepted the answer. Thanks for youre help.

Comment: Hehe, thanks. Notice that my script enables the file if not exist, but: an empty CAD_Kunde.txt will cause an error. There must be at least two lines: 0 and first dataline with at least one release, and ending 0. It's your homework now to add those lines into new textfile, or create error protection against empty files. There is no dataline creator, you can make that too.

Comment: i wanted to know if its possible to store the last selection in an another file than the configs for the dropdownbox? I mean with this: the first line of CAD_Kunde.txt is the number stored for the last selection, but can it be stored in a different textfile in the current user profile? Is javascript able to use relatives path. Doesnt know an another way to contact you so i commented here. Hope you read it.

Comment: Well, I've expected this question. Answer for both questions is yes, but... According any FSO-documentation, both absolute and relative paths can  be used. Whenever I've tried to use a relative path, I've got a "File not found"-error. The default value can be stored as you proposed. In case you have to create an other reading-function, and also remove all stuff made for release-reading/saving from all functions + onchange-attribute from `select2`. Read carefully my js-code, there is all what you'll need.